# CakePHP findbyList

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I'm getting data by CakePHP findbyList

```
Array
(
    [92] => 5
    [93] => 5
    [98] => 5
)
```

**CODE**

```
$get = array(
    'fields' => array('Upload.type'),
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'alias' => 't',
            'table' => 'temp_files',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array('Upload.id = t.file_id')
        ),
        array(
            'alias' => 'o',
            'table' => 'orders',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array('o.batch_id = t.batch_id')
        )
    ),
    'conditions' => array('OR'=>array('o.user_id '=>$user['id'],'t.user_id '=>$user['id'])),
    'group' => 'Upload.id'
);

$files = $this->find('list',$get);
```

Is there any way in CakePHP for getting data like:

```
Array
(
    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 92
            [1] => 93
            [2] => 98
        )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is two cakephp ways to retrive results like yours:

**Find threaded:**

**https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-threaded**

and use **Hash utility** to extract, combine , etc your results:

**https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html**

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how your database looks like I would probably use `$this->find('all',$get)` instead of `'list'`

List will always put the ID of your model as a key, so it will never work as you need.

Comment: In short, there is no way...  Okay! No problem. I've done it by PHP. Thanks for the response.

Comment: No, there's almost certainly a way. He said that *list* will not work that way. We'd need more information to suggest a better solution.

Comment: yes, we need the db structure and how the table classes are linked to be able to do a query :)

Answer (score 0):

It would have been much better to understand this situation if db structure would have been mentioned.
Anyways what I would suggest is to to use **$this->find('all',$get)** instead of list and you can play around your final result array by managing the way you need your final output array.

Answer (score 0):

EX:- if you get the list of the user name with userID then you are using CakePHP collection in CakePHP query.
CakePHP collection here :[CakePHP Collection](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/collections.html#Cake%5CCollection%5CCollection::combine)

```
$userList = $this->find()
                ->where(['status' => Configure::read('Status.active')])
                ->order(['first_name' => 'ASC'])
                ->combine('id','name')
                ->toArray();
```

in this result in userID is a key and name as a value display.